# verisign certificate into jboss server SSL

Tags: ssl, jboss

i'm trying to enable jboss to uses ssl protocol using a previously generated certificate from verisign, i imported both certificate, server certificate and ca certificate into the keytore file, and i configured the server.xml to use that keystore and activate ssl protocol, then when i run the jboss, I got this error "certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled"

Question, reading some post on internet, i found that every example was made it generating a Certificate Request, it stricly necesary to do that if i already have the server certificate and that CSR has to be imported into the keystore as well ? at this point i'm very confused about this issue, i tried almost every solutions posted in several forums but till now i haven't any luck !! can you give me some tips in order to solve this problem.

thanks in advance

this are my keystore file: Keystore type: jks Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

j2ee, Dec 29, 2009, trustedCertEntry, Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 69:CC:2D:2A:2D:EF:C4:DB:A2:26:35:57:06:29:7D:4C ugent, Dec 29, 2009, trustedCertEntry, Certificate fingerprint (MD5): AC:D8:0E:A2:7B:B7:2C:E7:00:DC:22:72:4A:5F:1E:92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found a solution for this problem, as you said i need to have my private key, server certificate and ca certificate into my keystore, in this post they explains how to import this 3 existing elements (as in my case) into the keystore using a very useful tool called keyman.  http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=532461

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You are almost certainly missing the concept of "private key". You need to have both the private key and the corresponding certified public key for your server. The usual way to do this is to generate a key with keytool with alias say 'mykey', export the pkcs#10 CSR with keytool, get this signed by Verisign (or whomever), then import the signed certificate back into the same keystore with keytool using the same alias 'mykey'. You can also import existing keypairs using keytool, but it can be more painful.